# How are 2nd year tax filing for coronavirus related early withdrawal entered?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, 401k

I need help understanding how/where to enter the 2nd year's worth of the 3 year spread of tax on 2020's coronavirus 401k withdrawal. How do you file the 2nd and 3rd year? The first year I got 2 1099R's for portions of the $100k I withdrew. I elected to spread it across 3 years. Do I use the orgininal 1099R's for entering each of the 3 years?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find any explicit guidance, so I would suggest to just report it on line 4a of the form 1040 and attach a statement. If you're using a tax preparation software, check if they add support for this use case (you may want to hold off filing until closer to the due date).